# How can I rewrite a [style.display] without using inline styles?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, content-security-policy

I have some angular code that contains some inline styles that I need to remove. Reason being is we need this code to be CSP compliant and CSP has issues with inline styles.

```
<div class="ccav-notify-pannel-wrapper" *ngIf="ccavShowWarningPanel" [style.display] ="!collapseAccountOverview? 'inherit': none">
```

What is a different way I can implement this exact logic maybe in typescript without using inline styles?

Comment: Instead of `[style.display]` you can use https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass and move styles to separate file.

Comment: Alternatively, you could consider securing scripts with CSP which use nonce's and allow `unsafe-inline`. https://angular.io/guide/security#content-security-policy

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngClass directives, red and green are css class names

```
<td [ngClass]="val > 10 ? 'red' : 'green'">{{ val }}</td>
```